# Connections in 3-phase AC circuits

Tags: ac, three-phase, homework

Does the supply voltage refer to the line voltage or the phase voltage here?

[image]

Comment: (My guess: Anybody's guess. But 230 V *phase voltage* is somewhat common, while I don't know where it would be used as line voltage - oh, pre-1985 Belgium.)

Comment: *Supply* voltage almost always refers to the *Line* voltage, measured between 2 phases.

Comment: @greybeard Norway still have 230 V phase voltage.

Comment: @winny large parts of the world do, including EU. 230 V *line* voltage/133 V phase voltage seems to have fallen out of favour.

Comment: @greybeard Dang it. I meant line-line. Norway is 230 with EU being 400 V

Comment: @greybeard - this is a school exercise, I wouldn't assume that it has any basis in reality.

Comment: It means line voltage in which there are three phase voltage lines with each 120 degrees apart connected to star (Y) or delta connected load.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear, from the statement of the problem, that it refers to the following cases:

1. A balanced three-phase, star-connected load across a
   3 x 230 V ~ supply.

   [image]
2. A balanced three-phase, delta-connected load across a
   3 x 230 V ~ supply.

   [image]